# How to submit the form without leaving the main index.php using external php file?

Tags: php, html

So, here is my html form code:

```
<form id="login_form" action="login.php" method="POST">
    <h2>Already a member? Sign in!</h2>
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

I included the external "login.php" file top of the page, and this is how it looks like:

```
<?php

    include 'config.php';

    if (isset($_POST["login_submit"]))
    {

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $query = "SELECT username, hashed_password FROM users WHERE username = '$username';";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $rows_num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($rows_num == 0) {
            echo "This user doesn't exist!";
        }
        else {
            $password_match = password_verify($password, $row['hashed_password']);
            if (!$password_match) {
                echo "The passwords do not match.";
            }
            else {
                header("Location: index.php");
                echo "Welcome ".$username."!";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

So, the logging system works well, but after press Sign in, it redirects to login.php and depending on the entered datas, it shows the result of the log in. How to do that, the login.php is just running in the background after hitting the submit button on index.php, and the result of the login appears under the login form insetad of login.php?

I know it's a horribly easy thing, but I just can't do that.

Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Your code looks alright, you're just missing the keyword to search what makes the magic happen. The technique is called an `Ajax request`. Do a Google search and you would find thousands of examples.

Comment: This isn't something PHP can do on it's own. You would need to use JavaScript to capture the form submit and perform an ajax request to your php script.

Answer (score 2):

## [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

If I understand your question correctly you want to submit the form without navigating away from the page you are on.  To do this you use javascript to make an xhr request or more commonly refereed to as an ajax request.

jQuery is not required to do this, but it makes it much easier.

## [On Submit Event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$( "#login_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formdata = $( this ).serializeArray();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"login.php",
    data: formdata,
    success: function() {
      // do something?
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You cannot use `this`. You should let the script know of its context: `context: this` before you can use `this`

Comment: good catch! updated answer.  Though it seems that I completely missed what the OP was trying to do so I don't think this answer is useful anymore :\